# Disable/Hide Sign in as a different user

Tags: user-controls

Need help in disabling or hiding ''Sign in as a different user'' in SharePoint site.

Comment: Do you have SP 2010 or 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it by dropping this piece of Javascript onto the Masterpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var doc = document.getElementsByTagName('ie:menuitem');  
for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++)  
{
    itm = doc[i];
    if (itm.id.match('LoginAsDifferentUser') != null)
      { itm.hidden=true; }
 } 
</script>
```

This works for SharePoint 2010, I haven't tested this on 2013.

Comment: SP 13 does not have this option either!

Comment: I am getting Server Error in '/' Application - runtime error. I am using SP 2010.